# virto commerce deployement from Github

Tags: virtocommerce

I have successfully deployed the virto platform and storefront on to azure.

the CMS content connection string was taken from the platform appsettings and assigned to the storefront CMS connection setting. The Api Hmac App Id and secret keys are assigned as per the documentation.

Platform and storefront are synced in azure with the latest.

however, when the storefront url is entered in the browser, it does not show the storefront, insted the following error occurs.

This page isn’t working our storename.azurewebsites.net is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

please advise if anyone encountered such error. Did I miss any other settings?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that is NOT CMS connection string related issue.

Second, try these:

- restart platform app service
- restart storefront app service
- clear browser cookies / open page in anonymous mode. The url should start with https, not http
- wait for 30 seconds as this could be a timeout issue on slower service configurations

Third: set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2#set-the-environment to get error stacktrace